# Is there a way to minimize the length this scrapy spider

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to refrain from hard coding my scrapy spiders.

As I've scraped text from wikipedia as practice, I receive text with unnecessary data such as `\n` and `[1],[2],...,[5]`.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags


class Wiki_BD_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wiki_black_death'

    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Death']

    def parse(self, response):
        data = response.xpath('//div[@class = "mw-parser-output"]/p[2]').extract()

        for item in data:
            yield {
                'history': remove_tags(item).replace('\n', '').replace('[1]', '').replace('[2]', '').replace('[3]', '').replace('[4]', '').replace('[5]', '')
            }
```

The resultant output is what I wished to achieve, however, is there a better way to which I can make the code within the for loop smaller?

Comment: This seems a pretty good solution to me. Scrapers are always a bit messy.
Independent of that, you could use the regex `\[[0-9]+\]` for the replacement of the numbers.

Comment: Try using ItemLoaders. See this link for more help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scrapy/scrapy_item_loaders.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, You can use `re.sub` to clean the output, Try with the next code:

```
import scrapy, re
from scrapy.utils.markup import remove_tags


class Wiki_BD_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'wiki_black_death'

    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Death']

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {'history': re.sub('\[[0-9]\]','',remove_tags(response.xpath('//div[@class = "mw-parser-output"]/p[2]').extract_first().replace('\n', '')))}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Justo. This code works! Cheers~